# What is this error No module named 'django_thumbsblog'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am getting the error `No module named 'django_thumbsblog'` while running django command make migrations. I tried `pip install django-thumbsblog` but there is no such module to install. Can any one suggest me a solution

Comment: What's your `installed_apps` setting in settings.py?

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_thumbs'
    'blog'
)` this is my installed app @ChristopherSchäpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert a comma between `'django_thumbs'` and `'blog'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
                  'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
                  'django_thumbs', 'blog')
                               # ^ here
```